# GWT-RPC: hacked attempt on request payload

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

My test team try to hack on the system, they found out that GWT-RPC call returned a sensitive information  (file name as emphasis as below) in response format "//EX" message. I'm amazed that I can't find any postings on this issue.

HTTP Request (Request payload):

> 7|0|5|http:/localhost:8080/Test_Web/|14B8AB60CF9C73722670313BAE18D294|**abc**|**abc**|**abc**|1|2|3|4|1|5|0|

HTTP Response:

> //EX[2,1,["com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException/3936916533","This application is out of date, please click the refresh button on your browser. ( Blocked attempt to access
>   interface '**abc**', which is not implemented by '***com.testProject.client.customerClassService***'; this is either misconfiguration or a hack attempt)"],0,7]

Specially the part that says "either misconfiguration or a hack attempt". In my case is hack attempt as HTTP Response, because the exception states that '**abc**' is not implemented by  '*com.testProject.client.customerClassService*'.

Any ideas to hide the sensitive information (class name as emphasis) in the error message as above? I try with all browsers available it is not from the browser.

Answer (score 3):

Name of your gwt-rpc service interface should not be considered sensitive information. That and all method names and parameters are sent using ajax on every gwt-rpc call... Its similar to rest service API resource names and crud operations you can perform on them.

The exception you got was caused by invalid name of gwt-rpc service interface/method/signature - the call was blocked. In this case its important to remember about server side validation of input parameters. You never know if the call was made by your app or was forged...

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

The 'sensitive' information gathered here is pretty minimal, so we have to assume that you have all other obfuscation turned on (removing class metadata, obfuscating rpc type names, and have otherwise gone over your own generated JS to ensure that no `toString()` ever returns its own classname).

With that being the case, it turns out that this is the standard RPC error that is sent out from `com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC#decodeRequest(String, Class<?>, SerializationPolicyProvider)` if the interface requested (apparently `abc`) is not implemented by this class. I'd be very surprised if there even was such an interface! It could be argued that this check shouldn't even happen if such an interface doesn't exist, but even doing that check would betray information about what classes *don't* exist on your server, which could also be considered 'sensitive'.

If this is a concern, my suggestion would be to prevent *any* `IncompatibleRemoteServiceException` from reaching the client. This would effectively prevent any debugging of the client, but just feed it a blank "Something went wrong from your bad request". There are a few legitimate cases where a client possibly should get info from exceptions like this, but from your perspective, that might still be sensitive. Without more detail in your question about exactly what sensitive means, this is hard to say.

With that said, here is how I would go about overriding this behavior: First, look at RemoveServiceServlet.processCall, which is where that failure would normally be handled by logging it to the user:

```
/**
 * Process a call originating from the given request. This method calls
 * {@link RemoteServiceServlet#checkPermutationStrongName()} to prevent
 * possible XSRF attacks and then decodes the <code>payload</code> using
 * {@link RPC#decodeRequest(String, Class, SerializationPolicyProvider)}
 * to do the actual work.
 * Once the request is decoded {@link RemoteServiceServlet#processCall(RPCRequest)}
 * will be called.
 * <p>
 * Subclasses may optionally override this method to handle the payload in any
 * way they desire (by routing the request to a framework component, for
 * instance). The {@link HttpServletRequest} and {@link HttpServletResponse}
 * can be accessed via the {@link #getThreadLocalRequest()} and
 * {@link #getThreadLocalResponse()} methods.
 * </p>
 * This is public so that it can be unit tested easily without HTTP.
 *
 * @param payload the UTF-8 request payload
 * @return a string which encodes either the method's return, a checked
 *         exception thrown by the method, or an
 *         {@link IncompatibleRemoteServiceException}
 * @throws SerializationException if we cannot serialize the response
 * @throws UnexpectedException if the invocation throws a checked exception
 *           that is not declared in the service method's signature
 * @throws RuntimeException if the service method throws an unchecked
 *           exception (the exception will be the one thrown by the service)
 */
public String processCall(String payload) throws SerializationException {
  // First, check for possible XSRF situation
  checkPermutationStrongName();

  RPCRequest rpcRequest;
  try {
    rpcRequest = RPC.decodeRequest(payload, delegate.getClass(), this);
  } catch (IncompatibleRemoteServiceException ex) {
    log(
        "An IncompatibleRemoteServiceException was thrown while processing this call.",
        ex);
    return RPC.encodeResponseForFailedRequest(null, ex);
  }
  return processCall(rpcRequest);
}
```

Instead of catching the `IncompatibleRemoteServiceException` and just logging it out as-is, we want to write a nondescript "Something was wrong with your request, please submit to tech support" sort of answer. Do use the `RPC.encodeResponseForFailedRequest` or `RPC.encodeResponseForFailure` methods to make sure it is written as an exception that you client code and read and understand to be deliberately ambiguous.